# Infragistics Date Picker -- Select Day, Not Year

Tags: .net, ipad, datepicker, infragistics

I'm working on a web app that utilizes Infragistics' Date Picker form component for .Net and I'm running into an issue I can't find any solution to here or elsewhere. Here's some sample code:

```
<igtxt:WebDateTimeEdit ID="tbBirthDate"  runat="server" placeholder="01/01/1980" class="form-control">
            </igtxt:WebDateTimeEdit>
```

As you can see, I'm using the component in a DD/MM/YYYY format and my client wants, on touchstart on an iPad within the form field, to be able to have the cursor begin at the far left of the component, or within the day area, not at the far right or at the end of the year area. This functionality does work on a desktop but on an iPad (presumably other mobile devices, as well) this appears to be a default behavior. Is there a way to make selecting the day region default across all devices/platforms? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me.

UPDATE: Adding graphic below to clarify the issue (taken from Chrome emulation of iPad 3/4):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me which version of Infragistics ASP.NET controls you are using? It seems that you are using the Ultra packet, which we don't support anymore. Can you try this [sample](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/editors/date-time-editor-localization), which is using the WebDateTimeEditor control and see if you are going to have such an issue. I'm testing it under iOS version 8.2 and Chrome version 38.0.2125.59 and I'm able to put the cursor at the beginning, at the end and I'm also able to select the day also.

Comment: Well, I'm "Jimi," not "Ricky" -- :) -- but I am passing these details along to the senior .Net developer who installed the components and we'll see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, Jimi. I'm not really sure where I saw the "Ricky" name, but I hope you are not offended. Best regards, Nikolay!

Comment: No problem -- the lead .Net developer says: "We are using Version=8.2.20082.1000". Don't know if that's helpful or not.